# A UIButton above a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, button, ios-simulator, uipickerview, device

I have a UIPickerView which works correctly, now I want to add a button above it so that I can dismiss it.

and here is my code where I initiate a UIPickerView as well as its dismiss button:

```
- (UIPickerView *)creatPickerView {
    UIPickerView *tempPickerView = [[[UIPickerView alloc] 
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPickerViewX, kPickerViewY, kPickerViewWidth, kPickerViewHeight)] autorelease];
    tempPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    tempPickerView.delegate = self;
    tempPickerView.dataSource = self;
    UIButton *pickerButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, -32, 50, 32)];
    [pickerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hidePicker.png"] 
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pickerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hidePicker)   
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tempPickerView addSubview:pickerButton];
    [pickerButton release];

    [self.view addSubview:tempPickerView];
    return tempPickerView;
}
```

and it works well on my iPhone 4.3 Simulator, like this:

[image]

apparently there is a button on the upper right of the pickerView,

problem is, when I run the app in my device - a 5.0.1 iPhone4 and a 4.2.1 iTouch, the button is missed like it has never been added to the pickerView.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot and a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, it seems the png has some problem,

after I change another png, it comes up in the screen!

but the real problem is that I place the button outside of the pickerView which results in the button's untouchableness.

But anyway the pickure is only a small problem.